# Solucionar lentitud en primera carga y glitch en Datagrid SQL WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Cuando guardo los datos por primera vez tarda unos 2 segundos en cargar luego de esa primera carga,la velocidad mejora pero a partir de allí con cada una se produce una especie de Glitch en el datagrid donde las columnas aperecen comprimidas y luego se expanden dura una milesima pero se nota.Nose si tiene que ver con la parte en donde le asigno al Item source del Datagrid el datable y o si es por otra cosa pero no encuentro a que se debe.Ademas antes habia realizado una clase que manejo esto y la cosa fue a peor tarda mas y el glitch se nota mas.Desde ya gracias

```
        SqlConnection coneccion;
        SqlCommand command;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            coneccion = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Conectar);
        }

        public void Buscar(string cabecera, string contenido)
        {
            try
            {
                coneccion.Open();
                string Consulta = "Select * from PRODUCTOS where " + cabecera + " =  " + contenido + "  ";
                command = new SqlCommand(Consulta, coneccion);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                nFilas = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("PRODUCTOS");
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                nFilas = dt.Rows.Count;
                coneccion.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
        public void ActualizarContenido()
        {
            try
            {
                coneccion.Open();
                string Consulta = "Select * from PRODUCTOS ";
                command = new SqlCommand(Consulta, coneccion);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                coneccion.Close();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("PRODUCTOS");
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                DataAlimentos.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
        public void Cargar()
        {
            try
            {
                string col = "DESCRIPCION,PRECIO,DISPONIBLE,CATEGORIA,PROVEEDOR";
                string datos = "'" + TxtProducto.Text + "','" + TxtPrecio.Text + "','" + TxtDisponible.Text + "','" + TxtCategoria.Text + "','" + TxtProveedor.Text + "' ";
                string identidad = "'" + TxtProducto.Text + "'";
                string identificador = "DESCRIPCION";
                Buscar(identificador, identidad);//Existe?

                if (nFilas > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El producto ya existe ");
                }
                else
                {
                    coneccion.Open();
                    string Consulta = "Insert into PRODUCTOS  (" + col + ") Values (" + datos + ")";
                    command = new SqlCommand(Consulta, coneccion);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    coneccion.Close();
                    ActualizarContenido();
                    MessageBox.Show("Guardado");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void BtnGuardar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cargar();
        }
```

Comment: El glitch justamente es por eso ya que el DataGrid no sabe qué cosa es lo que le estás cargando, simplemente borra todo y se adapta al nuevo contenido (aunque sea el mismo), si en realidad te molesta el glitch puedes declarar las columnas en el XAML y de ese modo el DataGrid siempre sabrá cuáles son las columnas que debe mostrar y las desplegará aunque el ItemsSource esté vacío, puedes jugar con el ColumnWidth del DataGrid... Respecto a la velocidad, es mas o menos normal que la primera vez se tarde más, ya que luego de esos ciertos datos permanecen en la memoria por si los necesitas otra vez.